# Issue generating longitude and latitude with ggmap using city and state columns in R

Tags: r, geolocation, geocoding, latitude-longitude, ggmap

I need to generate longitude and latitude given the two columns "city" and "state" where for example city = "Denver City" and state = "TX"

Using the following:

```
lonlat <- geocode(unique(sample_data$city, sample_data$state, method = "census")) 
locations <- cbind(sample_data, lonlat)
```

I am given the output of longitude = -104.9903 and latitude = 39.73924. These are the coordinates for Denver Colorado, not Denver City Texas. Any advice?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the `tidygeocoder` package (inferring from `geocode` function), but does it have an S3 method for `unique`? Perhaps your code should be `geocode(unique(sample_data$city, sample_data$state), method="census")`? But even then, `base::unique` is only going to operate on one vector, so only `sample_data$city` is used here, the `sample_data$state` argument may be inadvertently assigned to the `incomparables=` argument.

Comment: Perhaps `geocode(unique(sample_data[,c("city","state")]), method="census")`?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with a super simple solution

```
sample_data$locations <- paste(sample_data$city, sample_data$state)
```

then

```
lonlat <- geocode(unique(sample_data$location, method = "census")) 
locations <- cbind(sample_data, lonlat)
```